# Photoshop shadow значения в layer shadow

Tags: swift, photoshop

Каким образом нужно переводить параметры тени фотошопа в параметры тени у view layer?

Opacity понятно, оно и там и там Opacity. А остальное?

> Фотошоп
>
> Blend Mode: Multiply
>
> Angle: 120
>
> Distance: 4
>
> Spread: 0
>
> Size: 21

Как эти значения перевести в значения

> layer.shadowOffset
>
> layer.shadowRadius
>
> layer.shadowPath?